# How to set Ceph chunk size?

Tags: ceph

I've read in [this article](http://www.networkcomputing.com/storage/gluster-vs-ceph-open-source-storage-goes-head-to-head/a/d-id/1113581) that adjusting Ceph's chunk size can improve its performance. How is that set? [This document](http://ceph.com/docs/master/man/8/cephfs/) explains how to set the stripe size. Is that what the first article means by "chunk size"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ceph, at its core, doesn't have a "chunk size" (term used in the article, but not on the docs).  The RADOS layer stores objects as a whole, without any splitting or striping.

It's the other layers that do striping of their data into several RADOS objects.

If you're using RGW (for S3/Swift compatibility), check [the Ceph Object Gateway Config Reference](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/config-ref/) for `rgw object stripe size`.

For RBD (block device access), check the `--stripe-unit` argument to the [`rbd create` command](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/man/8/rbd/).

Finally, for CephFS (mountable filesystem), in [the manpage you refer](http://ceph.com/docs/master/man/8/cephfs/), the `--stripe_unit` argument is the size of each stripe.

Comment: Have you found that changing the stripe size has an impact on IOPS?

Comment: I've tried tweaking stripe-unit/stripe-count/order with no significant impact on performance. This is running Ceph on a local VirtualBox cluster with 2-4 OSDs. Next step is to try this on on a bigger scale.